# Why does my form take every entry and pass them to the php apart from the last one?

Tags: php

I am using the following form to try and take the data to update my database.

```
<form id="dataForm" action="addToProducts.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <lable >Product Name:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="addName" type="text" name="Name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <lable>Description:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="addDescription" type="text" name="description">
  </div>
  <div>
    <lable>Price:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="addPrice" type="text" name="Price">
  </div>
  <div>
    <lable>Quantity:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="addQuantity" type"text" name"quantity">
  </div> 
  <div id="theSubmit">
    <button id="addButton">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

I then am using the following php code to update the database. When i run the following code by clicking submit it passes all the values into the database apart from the quantity and leaves it at 0 and i can not work out why after several hours of looking at it.
Here is the php code..

```
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
     $Description = $_POST['description'];
     $Price = $_POST['Price'];
     $Quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (P_Name, P_Description, P_Price, P_Quantity) VALUES ('$Name', '$Description', '$Price', '$Quantity') ";
     $conn->exec($sql);
```

any pointers would be a great help

Comment: I'm sure that's not how you spell `<label>` ... and even if you corrected it, it'll do nothing since it neither wraps the `<input>` nor has a `for` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missed an '=' here

```
<lable>Quantity:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="addQuantity" type"text" name"quantity">
```

changed to

```
<lable>Quantity:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="addQuantity" type="text" name="quantity">
```

Comment: omg that is it, this has been doing me in for hours and its a stupid = that ive missed, god i feel embarrassed haha, thanks!

Comment: @thomas: Also, you need to check your spelling for `label` tags. And if the datatype of `P_Quantity` is `int`, make sure you remove the `'` around `$Quantity` from the insert query.

Answer (score 0):

```
type"text" name"quantity"
```

You're missing a '=' there.

Try changing it to:

```
type="text" name="quantity"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="dataForm" action="addToProducts.php" method="POST">
<div>
<label>Product Name:</label>
<input class="inputForm" id="addName" type="text" name="Name">
</div>
<div>
<label>Description:</label>
<input class="inputForm" id="addDescription" type="text" name="description">
</div>
<div>
<label>Price:</label>
<input class="inputForm" id="addPrice" type="text" name="Price">
</div>
<div>
<label>Quantity:</label>
<input class="inputForm" id="addQuantity" type="text" name"quantity">
</div> 
<div id="theSubmit">
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="addButton">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this `<input class="inputForm" id="addQuantity" type = "text" name = "quantity">`

instead of `<input class="inputForm" id="addQuantity" type"text" name"quantity">`